# Why does the batch file I created to stop and start a windows service not working correctly

Tags: batch-file, windows-services, scheduled-tasks, admin, windows-task-scheduler

My batch file that I created to stop and then start windows service won't run and throws back an error
Each time I run the file as Admin (I am the only user that's on this machine and the account is an admin account).
I have tested my batch file on its own and not in task scheduler and it works perfectly fine when I run the batch file as admin. However, it falls over when I try set up a daily task on Task Scheduler.

I have a simple batch file that stops and starts a service. for reference this is what it looks like:

```
Net Stop "StorSvc"
Net Start "StorSvc"
```

I have run this as admin and it worked fine. I then created a task to do this daily at a certain time. I placed the file in C: Drive and attached the file to my task scheduler.

On the security options I have ticked

- **"Run whether user is logged on or not"**
- **"Run with the highest privileges"**
  I have changed the "When running the task use the following user account" to my account, Systems and other admin options that show up. I even selected "System"

When I click ok it prompts me to sign in to the admin account. when I do this it says
**"An error has occurred for task StorSvc" Error message. One or more of the specified arguments are not valid"**

All of the last run results are as listed below:
0x800710E0
0x41303
0x2

Comment: This may be of use: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/657f03a9-2d19-42e1-a998-6ddfaeb0a07f/task-scheduler-the-operator-or-administrator-has-refused-the-request-0x800710e0?forum=winserver8gen

Answer (score 0):

I have had better success with [sc.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html) for controlling services via batch file.

For your situation this should work:

```
sc.exe stop StorSvc
sc.exe start StorSvc
```

If that still gets credential issues you could include [PsExec.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) like this:

```
psexec.exe -u <user> -p <password> -c "sc.exe stop StorSvc"
psexec.exe -u <user> -p <password> -c "sc.exe start StorSvc"
```

Comment: Your answer is currently nothing but a link only, because your codebox snippet is completely irrelevant to the question. Please either submit code appropriate to the question asked or delete this answer, and submit a comment instead. (If you have insufficient reputation to comment, please try to gain that reputation by submitting relevant answers).